# From nested list [[name1,score],[name2,score],...], how do I remove the names with the lowest score?

Tags: python, nested

I have a mixed nested list `[[name1,score],[name2,score],...]`.
How do I remove the names with the lowest score? I selected an element with the lowest score and looped through the list and compared scores and remove if the score matches the min.

```
lmin=min(list, key = lambda x: x[1])
for l in list:
    if( ls[1] == lmin1[1]):
        ls1.remove(l)
```

But it doesn't remove all, only the first instance. Where am I making a mistake?
Best,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better way to filter:

```
lmin=min(list_, key = lambda x: x[1])
li = [ item for item in list_ if item[1] != lmin]
```

Note that you shouldnt use the word `list` as variable as it is a saved keyword...

Comment: Thanks. I tried list_ but didn't work. did without it and worked fine

Comment: You have to change all occurrences

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
Mylist = [["name1",10],["name2",4],["name3",40]]
print(Mylist)
to_remove=min(Mylist, key = lambda x: x[1])
Mylist.remove(to_remove)
print(Mylist)
```

result:

```
[['name1', 10], ['name2', 4], ['name3', 40]]
[['name1', 10], ['name3', 40]]
```

Comment: Is it removing duplicates too?